# Mono async exception handling

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm just trying to figure out how exception handling works in reactor library.

Consider the following example:

```
public class FluxTest {

@Test
public void testIt() throws InterruptedException {
    Scheduler single = Schedulers.single();

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Mono.just("hey")
            .subscribeOn(single)
            .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("ERROR1: " + e.getMessage()))
            .doOnTerminate((r, e) -> {
                if (e != null) System.out.println("ERROR3: " + e.getMessage());
                latch.countDown();
            })
            .subscribe(
                    it -> { throw new RuntimeException("Error for " + it); },
                    ex -> { System.out.println("ERROR2: " + ex.getMessage());}
                    );

    latch.await();
}

}
```

Actually, I can't see any of error handling code block executes.
Test terminates without any message. Also, I tried to remove `doOnError, doOnTerminate` processors with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And it's correct behavior in your case. 
You're creating mono from single string "hey" that has no errors. If you try to debug you can see that `doOnTerminate` method gets called with `e = null` parameter and according to documentation it gets called in any case `success` or `error`.

To test some error handling you can do next thing:

```
public class FluxTest {
    @Test
    public void testIt() throws InterruptedException {
        Scheduler single = Schedulers.single();

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Mono.just("hey")
                .map(this::mapWithException)
                .subscribeOn(single)
                .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("ERROR1: " + e.getMessage()))
                .doOnTerminate((r, e) -> {
                    if (e != null) System.out.println("ERROR3: " + e.getMessage());
                    latch.countDown();
                })
                .subscribe(
                        it -> { throw new RuntimeException("Error for " + it); },
                        ex -> { System.out.println("ERROR2: " + ex.getMessage());}
                        );

        latch.await();
    }

    private String mapWithException(String s) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

After running test with code above you should three lines in you console

```
ERROR1: null
ERROR3: null
ERROR2: null
```

So first callback is `onError` when mono failed, second will be `onTerminate` because mono is terminated with error and the third one `errorConsumer` from `subscribe` method.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer. So what is the right way to handle errors of sbscriber? Just process them in subscriber code?

Comment: @MaximGulimonov It depends, if you want to handle some errors with subscriber you should provide `errorConsumer` and if you want to handle errors in any case you should write `doOnError` method.

Comment: I mean, is that right that you can't handle errors raised by subscriber code using Flux constructions like `doOnError`, and errorConsumer lambda also can't handle such exceptions?

Comment: @mgulimonov Yes that is right, it should be subscribed responsibility to handle errors of itself.